# SQL Server - Does it really release memory when another process needs it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, memory

We have an 8 Core, 16GB RAM server that has SQL Server 2008 running on it. When we perform large queries on millions of rows the RAM usage goes up to 15.7GB and then even file browsing, opening excel etc gets really slow.

So does SQL Server really release memory when another process needs it or am I having another issue? We don't have any other major programs running on this server.

We've set a max memory usage of 14GB for SQL Server.

Thanks all for any enlightenment or trouble shooting ideas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it does. See [SQLOS's memory manager: responding to memory pressure](https://web.archive.org/web/20151030010554/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slavao/archive/2005/02/19/376714.aspx) for details how this works. But what exactly means to have 'memory pressure' it depends from machine to machine and from OS version to OS version, see [Q & A: Does SQL Server always respond to memory pressure?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/slavao/q-a-does-sql-server-always-respond-to-memory-pressure). If you want to reserve more memory for applications (I'm not even bother to ask *why* you browse files and use Excel on a machine dedicated to SQL Server....) then you should lower the mas server memory until it leaves enough for your entertainment.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server does NOT release memory. It takes all the memory it can get up to the MaxMemory setting and it stays there.

Comment: Really? Do you have a link to somewhere confirming this?

Comment: will this do? http://serverfault.com/questions/1279/reclaiming-memory-from-sql-server if you want it to release memory you'll have to lower the max memory setting.

Comment: That link says nothing about SQL Server not releasing memory but consuming as much as it needs. In your answer, you are basically saying it never releases memory, even if the OS dictates another process needs this memory?

Comment: Mladen is wrong. It CAN release and it WILL if it is ALLOWED to do so (setting on server level).

Comment: ok, maybe i should have been more clear. if SQL server gets mem pressure it'll be forced by the OS to release the memory. howevery when this mem perssure stops the mem will go up again if sql server had heavy use. This is a typical scenario for adding more RAM.

Comment: @TomTom what server level setting are you talking about? Max and Min memory?